# I can't change the activity theme in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, themes, look-and-feel

I'm using the activity design to try to change the theme.

Unfortunately, when I run the app on my phone, it consistently shows this blue color.
I don't know why it's blue or where this theme came from.
This issue only started appearing recently.
Any help?

Here's the relevant code.
Please keep in mind that this is simply an empty activity.
I have not modified the code in any way.
For some reason android studio defaults to this behavior.

To be clear, I tried changing the theme using the highlighted button in the second image.
No matter which theme I pick, all that changes is the activity view in the IDE.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[Screencap from phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibRd0.png)

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xlk0.png)

Comment: can you provide the code you are using and what color it is suppose to be

Comment: change the hex value in `<color name="colorPirmary">#3F51B5</color>` in your `styles.xml` to match what color you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change hex color value as what color you want in **colors.xml** like below

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#d3d3d3</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#a8a8a8</color>
</resources>
```

Change the parent theme as

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

instead

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: I'm aware of this. I managed to change the action bar and status bar. Unfortunately, I can't change the color of the text this way, making it impossible to see white text on a white background. Themes are the cleanest and simplest way of doing it but changes in theme have no effect. In addition, I don't know why my action bar is now blue by default.

Comment: It's not a total solution, but it worked well enough. I still don't understand why I can't actually change the theme. Doing what you said only changed the actionbar text color. I had to change the other colors manually. In any case, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier way  would be to create a different xml file to manage such issues. To do so, right click on your drawable folder-New -Drawable Resource File-Name.xml.

Then go online to http://angrytools.com/gradient/ and genetate whichever theme you desire. Get the code generated and paste it in the xml file you created.

Next, within your layout tag within the activity xml file, place the following 
line

```
android:background="@drawable/Name"
```

You can then modify your theme by editing the drawable file you created. Hope this helps